# Client side validation not working on Bootstrap modal on MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, client-side-validation

I have a page which list all Countries in a tabular form and view has a model like below:

```
@model IEnumerable<Country>
```

On the same page I have a link that allows the user to create a new Country via a modal popup(defined within that page)

```
<a operation="add" id="btnNewCountry" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#">Add New Country</a>
```

Model popup snippet looks like below:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
@using (Html.BeginForm("ManageCountry", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype ="multipart/form-data" }))
{
 <label for="module-text">Country Name</label>
 <input type="text" id="txtName" name="name" />

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
}
```

As soon as the user presses submit button, the  control quickly reaches the Controller Action.

Now the challenge is I am not able to figure out how to apply Client Side validation on the CountryName textbox  (something like **@Html.ValidationMessagefor** and **Required**) on the "Add New Country" Popup as the modal of the page( which is IEnumerable) is different from the Modal Popup (which works only on a single Country Object)

Please help!!

Comment: Why do you have `<label for="module-text">`? Your control is named `name`! Create a view model that contains properties for `IEnumerable<Country> Countries` and `Country NewCountry` so that you can bind the form to the properties of `NewCountry` using strongly typed helpers and post back your model

Comment: Thanks Stephen..let me try that..I will get back shortly on this with the results

Comment: Thanks a ton, An absolute solution..Did not know how I cannot thought in that direction.

Comment: One more issue I am seeing is if there are two fields, and I post the form without entering anything in any of them , it shows the ValidationMessage for both, and if I enter the value in any one of them, it post the form without prompting message for other field which is still blank??

Comment: @CuriousBuddy, You need to post your updated code or ask a new question (and next time you post a message, click on the 'help' button)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I have posted another question with entire code snippet as suggested: [Question Posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580609/client-side-validation-showing-strange-behavior-on-bootstrap-modal-mvc-view)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make sure that you have included the client-side validation framework to your bundles:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js","));
```

Then you can use the the [Required] Annotation on your property like this:

```
[Required]
public string CountryName {get; set;}
```

And now you can use the:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Model.CountryName)
```

to show the error message in the view.

EDIT:

If the browser supports HTML5, you can also just use ' required="" ' like this:

```
<input type="text" name="CountryName" required="">
```

EDIT:

Based on your comment, I would recommend you to use ViewModels. The simplest approach that requires no mapping, is to make a ViewModel like this:

```
[Required]
public List<Country> Countires { get; set; }
```

And in your controller, you can bind your data to the ViewModel Like this:

```
//This is the call, that returns an IEnumerable
var countries = _repository.GetCountries().ToList();

var viewModel = new ViewModel(){
     Countries = countries,
}
```

This way you don't work with the EF query directly in the view.

Comment: If this is not working - can you check your browser console to see, if there are any script errors on the page?

Comment: I know the above approach, issue is the model on my page is IEnumerable<Country> so I cannot bind CountryName like that

Comment: And then you can bind it, by doing: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Country.Name, new{ required=""})